# Duplicate entry for key mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Here's the error I'm shown when performing the SQL Query in question

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry '67302165' for key 'Player_Resource'
```

I understand this means that the record already exists, but it actually doesn't, here's what's returned when I run a `SELECT` query, to check against that specific `Player_Resource`

```
SELECT * FROM `players` WHERE `Player_Resource` = '67302165'

MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0003 sec)
```

And as for the `INSERT` query that I'm trying to perform, it's as followed;

```
INSERT INTO 
    `players` 
    (
        `Player_ID`, 
        `Player_Resource`, 
        `Player_Name`, 
        `Player_Common`, 
        `Player_Club`,
    ) 
SELECT 
    `Player_ID`, 
    '67302165', 
    Player_Name, 
    Player_Common, 
    Player_Club,
FROM 
    `players` 
WHERE 
    `Player_ID` = '193301'
```

The table description is like such

```
|      Field     |    Type        |   Null   |   Key   | Default |      Extra       |
+----------------+----------------+----------+---------+---------+------------------+
  Players_id         int(11)          NO        PRI      NULL       auto_increment
  Player_ID          int(6)           NO         0    
  Player_Resource    varchar(255)     NO        UNI       0
  Player_Name        varchar(255)     NO        NULL
  Player_Common      varchar(255)     NO        NULL  
  Player_Club        int(10)          NO        NULL
```

Any explainable reason as to why this error would be shown? bare in mind I've placed a `UNIQUE` Index on the `Player_Resource` column

Comment: Is there a chance that you have more than one row in that table with `Player_ID=193301`?

Comment: Can you show us the table description please?

Comment: @cherouvim that's correct, theirs 2 rows, but they both have a unique ID (not `Player_ID`) and both have a unique `Player_Resource`

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have more than one row in that table with `Player_ID=193301`. The fact that they have a different `Player_Resource` doesn't matter because you never use the actual value in your insert query. You use the fixed value of `67302165` in all insertions:

```
...
SELECT 
    `Player_ID`, 
    '67302165', 
    Player_Name, 
    Player_Common, 
    Player_Club,
FROM 
    `players` 
...
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing now anyway?

Comment: I'm explaining why you get the error. I'm not providing a solution because I don't know exactly what you are trying to achieve. Please read again.